# Pygame video system not initialized when making a sorting application

Tags: python, pygame

I've been working on a sorting application in python using pygame for visual purposes, and now I am experiencing an error which I am not sure how to fix. My code was working perfectly fine, and then I started getting an error which was saying "pygame.error: video system not initialized". Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random
import keyboard



pygame.font.init()
lines = [random.randint(1,25) for i in range(100)]


def line_draw():
    array_items = len(lines)
    line_color = (0,0,0)
    line_width = int(650 / array_items)
    list_pos = 1
    
    for i in lines:
        start_x = (800 / (array_items + 1)) * list_pos
        start_y = 600

        end_x = start_x
        end_y = 600 - (i * 20)

        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, line_color, (start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), line_width)
        list_pos = list_pos + 1

def refill():
    gameDisplay.fill((255,255,255))
    line_draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(3)


def bubble_sort():
    exchange = True
    elements = len(lines)
    passes_remaining = elements - 1
    
    while passes_remaining > 0 and exchange:
        exchange = False
        pygame.event.pump()
    
        for i in range(passes_remaining):
            if lines[i] > lines[i+1]:
                exchange = True

                temp = lines[i]
                lines[i] = lines[i+1]
                lines[i+1] = temp

            refill()
        passes_remaining = passes_remaining - 1   
                
            
       

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_o:
                bubble_sort()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                lines = [random.randint(1,25) for i in range(100)]
                line_draw()
        
    gameDisplay.fill((255, 255, 255))
    line_draw()    

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) and [`pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) is missing

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks! I just realized I accidentally deleted  the display initiation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialized to pygame modules (e.g. [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init)) and you must initialize a window or screen for display with [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), before the application loop:

```py
import pygame

# [...]

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

# [...]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
```